# angular 2 lazy loading of chunks with webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple angular2-cli project which uses webpack and I want to use the angular lazy loading feature to load modules.
The following works fine:

```
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: 'app/users/users.module#UsersModule',
  },
```

This code will bundle the users module as 0.chunk.js. For reasons like simplification I want load this chunk file directly, like:

```
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () => require("<...path>/0.chunk.js")
  },
```

But it I open the page it results in the error message

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): **Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'.**
Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (compiler.es5.js:13360) [angular]
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:13939) [angular]
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:25134) [angular]
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:25093) [angular]
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:25055) [angular]
    at ModuleBoundCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:25423) [angular]
```

Now my question: How is it possible?

Thank you very much!

R-on